# Create Opportunity Attachment from Document object record

Tags: apex

I am trying to create an opportunity attachment from an existing Salesforce Document using apex. I know how to create an attachment for an opportunity, but I am having trouble understanding how to link a document to the attachment body. Can someone please help explain with a code example in terms of how to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have to copy the Document's body into the Attachment's body

Comment: That worked! Thank you @cropredy! I knew it had to be a simple solution like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document` and `Attachment` are separate SObjects, each has a field called `Body`

If you are trying to put the content of a Document as an Attachment, then you need code something like this:

```
Document d = [select Id, Body, Name from Document where ...];
insert new Attachment(ParentId = someOppoId,
                      Body = d.Body,
                      Name = d.Name);
```

You might consider moving your `Document` to a `ContentDocument` (aka `File`) and then you can simply insert a `ContentDocumentLink` between the `Opportunity` and the `ContentDocument` - thus avoiding the copying of the body - something where heap size limits may create havoc. Any changes made to the ContentDocument are thus always reflected in all Opportunities that share it.

Of course, if you need to stamp an `Opportunity` with a `Document` as of a specific document version, then copying the `Document` into the `Attachment` may be the best way forward.